# How can I set specific duration for each dashboard using gem SinatraCyclist?

Tags: sinatra, dashing

Is there a way to set specific time/duration for specific dashboard using

gem 'sinatra_cyclist' [link here](https://github.com/vrish88/sinatra_cyclist).

**Documentation says**,

**Usage**

require "sinatra/base"
require "sinatra/cyclist"

```
class MyApp < Sinatra::Base
  register Sinatra::Cyclist

  set :routes_to_cycle_through, [:dashboard_1, :dashboard_2]
end
```

You can also specify a duration (in seconds) in the params to the cycle action

```
http://sinatra_app.com/_cycle?duration=10
```

**Yes**, it will cycle the 2 dashboards.

**Is it possible (or not) to set for example 60 seconds for the 1st dashboard and 30 seconds for the 2nd?**